# Unlimited max-width in responsive CSS

Tags: css

Can anyone tell me if I can set a "infinite" max-width for doing responsive web design?

Currently I have

```
@media screen and (max-width: 5000px) { }
```

But what if one day screen resolution is bigger than 5000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove that clause entirely.

If you don't want a maximum, don't set a maximum.

Answer (score 16):

You could set it to `max-width: none;` (Initial value) if you want, otherwise just don't set it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just include the default attributes in the class and then those values will change on resize, so no need to have a separate setting for unlimited.